# Extends a Error struct, but encounter Type '*MyError' has both field and method named 'Error'

Tags: go, error-handling

I come from java.

And I am using a framework that already define an `Error` in `errs` package, I want to extend it so that I can add more fields to it. So I try using inheritance of go.

```
// Error to inherit from errs.Error
type MyError struct {
    errs.Error
    ErrDetail string    //more message to my error
    st        []uintptr 
}

// override Error() so that the message can be more specific
func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    if e == nil {
        return ErrorCodeSuccess.ErrDetail
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("Code:%d, ErrDetail:%s, Msg:%s", e.GetCode(), e.GetErrDetail(), e.GetMsg())
}
```

This is very straightforward for a java programmer. But I get

```
 Type '*MyError' has both field and method named 'Error'.
```

This is very frustrating since the method Error is define in built-in package, and the name `Error` is define in my framework, is there any workaround to solve this problem？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [type alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations):

```
type SDKErr = errs.Error

// Error to inherit from errs.Error
type MyError struct {
    SDKErr
    ErrDetail string    //more message to my error
    st        []uintptr 
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    // ...
}
```

Now the name of the embedded field is `SDKErr`, but it won't conflict with the method name, and it can be used wherever `errs.Error` is expected without the need to convert.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/XSWi5hzHGPh

Of course you could also use a named field, instead of an alias:

```
type MyError struct {
    SDKErr errs.Error
    ErrDetail string    //more message to my error
    st        []uintptr 
}
```

And then call the methods of `errs.Error` simply like `e.SDKErr.GetCode()`. However if `MyError` is meant, for example, to be serialized to JSON, the fields of `errs.Error` would appear as a nested object, whereas with the type alias they would be "flattened".

Basically if `errs.Error` were defined as:

```
type Error struct {
    Code int
}
```

With the type alias and embedded field, JSON would look like:

```
{"Code":0,"ErrDetail":""}
```

vs named field:

```
{"SDKErr":{"Code":0},"ErrDetail":""}
```